# URL file to table scrape and save to csv

Tags: python, pandas, url, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am very new to coding in general. I know excel and some VBA but am getting stuck on putting the parts together. 
I have a list of URLs and the below gives me the output I want for 1 url but I have 500 URLs that have the same data. 
What I am trying to do is have it read the url file grab the data and save the output in to a csv. Please help me figure this out. I know it's simple and I found so many ways to do it but putting all the peaces together is hard.
Thanks
Mike

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv 

with open("tvlocation.csv","r") as file:
file.write('dfs = pd.read_html('tvurl.txt')
for df in dfs:
    print(df)

file.close()
```

Comment: You should check your indentation on your code from line 7 to 9. Also, what is your purpose? Reading the `csv` file or writing into `csv` file? If you want to save into `csv` file, it should be `'w'` instead of `'r'`. The single quote location and the closing bracket in line 7 also incorrect. May it help.

Comment: Well I want to write to the csv from the tables it's pulling the data from.How can I have it access the list of urls I have?

Comment: Have you succeeded to retrieve data from the URL? If not, could you show me the URL you want to scrape?

Comment: Well I was able to scrape the table data with the following code below. But when I tried to save it to a file and have it reference the list of urls I got stuck

import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv 


dfs = pd.read_html('https://nocable.org/browse-stations/callsign/cadenatres-linares-nl')
for df in dfs:
    print(df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 500 URLS, you can just save it to a file. You can then read the lines to a list and use [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html) on each, to get a dataframe list. Get the second column of the first dataframe to a list and use csv module to write it to the file.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
url_list=[]
with open('file.csv','w') as csvfile, open('urls.txt','r') as urlfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    #Write the headers
    writer.writerow(['State','City','Country','Callsign','Network Affiliation'])
    #Read urls into a list
    urls=urlfile.readlines()
    for url in urls:
        dfs = pd.read_html(url.strip())
        #convert second column of 1st dataframe to a list and write to csv file
        writer.writerow(list(dfs[0][1])[:-1])
```

*urls.txt*

```
https://nocable.org/browse-stations/callsign/cadenatres-linares-nl
https://nocable.org/browse-stations/callsign/k27hm-d-quanah-tx
```

*file.csv*

```
State,City,Country,Callsign,Network Affiliation
Newfoundland and Labrador,AGUALEGUAS,USA,CADENATRES,INDEPENDENT
Texas,QUANAH,USA,27,K27HM-D,INDEPENDENT
```

You might want to consider adding some random delay while using read_html on each url. Also If you want to do this in chunks of say 50 urls etc., then don't forget to change the write mode to 'a' from 'w' and remove code that writes the headers from the second time.

Comment: The second row has not enough column to put the data value of `27`.

Comment: @Yusufsn That url was not in the question. I added it for clarity that you can use multiple urls.

Comment: That worked I put a time.sleep to ensure I don't break anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of dictionary.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url_list = ['https://nocable.org/browse-stations/callsign/cadenatres-linares-nl',
            'https://nocable.org/browse-stations/callsign/k27hm-d-quanah-tx']
data = []
for url in url_list:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    urldict = {}
    tr = soup.find_all('tr')
    for row in tr:
        th = soup.find_all('th')
        td = soup.find_all('td')

    for item in range(0,len(th)):    
        urldict.update({th[item].text:td[item].text})

    data.append(urldict)
```

Define the columns you want to use as header in your `csv` file.

```
cols = []
for d in range(0,len(data)):
    for i in data[d].keys():
        if i not in cols:
            cols.insert(len(cols),i)
```

Then, save the list of dictionary to `csv` file.

```
with open('file_url.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, cols)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: @yusufan So I should be able to copy and paste this and it should work? Does it need a print() command or something?

Comment: Yes, you can copy and paste the code. However, you don't need to print anything for saving into `csv` file. But if you want to see the result, you can use `pandas` to read your `csv` file, or just check your `csv` file directly on your system.